# Modern Warfare 3 keeps freezing on PS3

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

So here I am getting ready to play some good 'ol MW3. I put the game disc in, load up multiplayer and select a game mode. I enter a match, play for a while, and then BAM. MW3 freezes. I mean freezes my whole console. I press the PlayStation button and it doesn't bring up the screen. I need help. I don't want to end up buying a new MW3 or PS3. I hope someone can tell me the problem with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thing happen.  At first it was once out of every 5 or so games and it got worse until eventually we couldn't get thru a game without it either giveing a "disc read error" or freezing the system completely.  We did all of the recommendations in the previous posts.  I cleaned the disc, I deleted add-ons, I tried whatever recommendations I could find.  I even took the disc into gamestop and they said it looked fine and there was no noticeable damage on the surface of the disc.  Since nothing else worked, I sent the disc back to Activision for a replacement.  It cost $20 to replace the disc if the game is no longer under warranty but that was cheaper than buying new so sent it back.  We got the replacement and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind, clean your disc.  I use a mild soap and hot water, only wiping from the center out in straight lines (not circular) and make sure it's really dry before you put it in.  Second make sure your PS3 is not overheating.  It should have at least 10-12 inches on all sides and possibly an intercooler or fan if your ambient temperature is warm.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar thing happen on my PS3 with Fallout: New Vegas. Go through your system and delete games and saves that you don't play anymore. If it continues to freeze, delete the game and re-install/re-update it.

Also to add to [what d34dhor53 was saying](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68131), if you do feel like your PS3 is overheating you could go a step further and either blow the dust out of it, or use a vacuum to suck it all up, or both. A dusty (inside) PS3 will heat up faster and get hotter then a nice clean one, and that can affect performance.